# How to apply flatMap to list of tuples (Int,String) in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, lambda, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I have the following `List` of tuples in Scala:

```
var a : List[(Int,String)] = List()
a = a:+((1,"bla bla bla"))
a = a:+((2,"la la la"))
a = a:+((3,"bla la bla"))
```

which looks like that:

```
print(a)
List((1,bla bla bla), (2,la la la), (3,bla la bla))
```

What I wish to do is to apply `flatMap` function in order to create a new list from the list `a` which contains only the strings from the tuple to which it appends the word "appended". The result should therefore be:

```
List(bla bla blaappended, la la laappended, bla la blaappended)
```

Could someone help me understand how I could go about it? I am new to Scala and I can't wrap my head around this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `flatMap`, simple `map` is enough

```
val result = a.map(t => t._2 + "appended")
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not want `flatMap` you want just a `map`, because you only want to perform a one to one transformation.
Also, for this kind of situations [**pattern matching**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html) is very helpful.
*(BTW, consider reading all the tour and other basic tutorials)*

```
// Avoid mutability ;)
val list : List[(Int,String)] = List(
  1 -> "bla bla bla",
  2 -> "la la la",
  3 -> "bla la bla"
)

val result = list.map {
  case (_, str) => s"${str} appended"
}
```

Comment: but what if I had a list of 10000000 entries and didnt know what String each entry includes? your code wouldnt scale

Comment: @hispaniccoder What do you mean? The solution is just the last 3 lines, which is the call to `map`. It is exactly the same code as the one proposed by Andronicus. The beginning of the code is just the creation of the list on a more idiomatic way that what you wrote on your question. That's all. - I really really recommend you to read the **tour** _(link in the answer)_ and any other basic tutorials as it seems you still struggle a lot reading and understating basic **Scala** code.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right! I am really sorry, but I totally misunderstood this